# How to find out failed insert script number among the multiple insertion scripts

Tags: oracle

My file.sql has 50000 insert scripts, in that one are more insert scripts exection failed because of the value is too large for the column, then how we can find out which insert script got failed (which line number of insert script failed in the file).

Comment: put dbms outputline each insert script

Comment: where did those 50,000 insert statements come from? it's likely they were derived from another source - go find THAT source and analyze the data there

Answer (score 0):

I take it you want the missing data to be inserted after all?

1 Can you delete all data, change the table to hold larger values and run the script again?

2 Is there a unique key on the table?  Then modify the table so it can hold larger values and run the script again. Only the data you do not already have will be inserted now.

3 Create the same table in another schema or database with the modified definition. Insert the data. Query the records where length of columns value > previous maximum. Generate insert statements only for these records and run these on the original (but now modified to hold larger values) table.